# ASPX SQL Parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sqlparameter

I'm trying to make a filtered list based on the user's input and lack of input.

I am able to filter if the user has inputted a whole name or just the first character of a name, I have 3 different textboxes (name, surname, country) that's used for the filter. In SQL Server I have created the code to do this and to filter even if they don't input a value into one or all of the textboxes. So I believe the SQL stored procedure is fine.

I believe my issue is when I'm trying to grab this information from a user in Visual Studio through textboxes and using the SQL Parameters to send the information to the stored procedure. I have noticed that I can't get an empty string into the SQL Paramete. Is there anyway I get pass an empty string to a SQL parameter?

Here is the bits of code...

The relevant bits from the stored procedure:

```
@Namenvarchar(100) = ' ',
@Surname nvarchar(100) = ' ',
@Country nvarchar(100) = ' '

AND IsNull(Input.Name, '')  LIKE '%' + @Name+ '%'
AND IsNull(Input.Surname, '') LIKE '%' + @Surname + '%' 
AND IsNull(Input.Country, '') LIKE '%' + @Country + '%'
```

And here is the code related to the Visual Studio side:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("FilterBasedOnInput", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

SqlParameter Name = new SqlParameter("@Name",  TBName.Text);
SqlParameter Surname= new SqlParameter("@Surname",  TBSurname.Text);
SqlParameter Country= new SqlParameter("@Country",  TBCountry.Text);


cmd.Parameters.Add(Name);
cmd.Parameters.Add(Surname);
cmd.Parameters.Add(Country);

con.Open();
```

So lets say in the DB I have the...

```
Names ("Tom", "Jones", "Nick")
Surname ("To", "Jo", "Ni")
Country ("England", "USA", "France")
```

If the user enters in the in the Name textbox "O", then both Tom and Jones would come up with their 3 columns but if they entered into the Surname textbox as well with "To" then only Tom would appear with his 3 columns.
I do have this working on SQL Server but not in Visual Studio ASPX.

Comment: You probably don't want to do what you are asking. If you use DBNull.Value instead you can filter your `WHERE` clause as `ISNULL(@param, [the_column])`. That way if the parameter has a value you filter on it but if not there is effectively no filter.

Comment: you can set your param as something before you feed it to the query. something like 'if txt.txt == '''' then "%" or something like that.

Comment: Can you post a excerpt of your code, and your stored procedure?

Comment: `= NULL` will never be true. You want `IS NULL` instead.

Comment: I did come across that but and I changed the code to show but it made no difference D Stanley

Answer (score 0):

Alright guys, I found the answer and it's in the GridView!

I was displaying the data and when you configure the gridview, there's a Default Value column, just put %

Now I am able to retrieve values even with an empty textbox or two.

Thank you all for your guidance, it lend to solving this problem.!